# Bad font rendering with some applications and good rendering in others, Windows 10

Tags: windows, display, fonts, rendering, high-definition

I've switched from my laptop screen to a bigger monitor (1920 x 1080) that I connect with hdmi. I've set dimensions of windows and everything at 125% in screen settings. After set up the ClearType, now I see good rendering on common windows, but bad rendering in others. For example, uTorrent and Steam have bad rendering, Chrome has good rendering.

Have you got a solution?

[image: Here you can see the difference between uTorrent and browser]

Comment: If you change it (back) to 100% in screen settings, do all application look OK?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 yep, switching to 100% everything is ok, all the fonts are the same in all the programs. Also, trying 150% doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to solve this problem.

This is related to DPI awareness. Some applications scale well, others don't.

It is possible to solve the problem one-by-one right-clicking on the **.exe**, **Proprieties**, **Compatibility** and turn off "**display scaling on high DPI device**".

I don't know a general solution that will disable that for all the programs.

Answer (score 0):

In screen properties set scaling to 100%, than click nearby at "advanced properties", enter here user scaling factor "125" and disable "allow windows..." button.
That worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).